# GDB Warning: Loadable section not found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7ffd000

Tags: linux, gcc, gdb

```
abijith bufferOverFlow $ gdb a.out
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/abijith/Project/Security/bufferOverFlow/a.out...done
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/abijith/Projec2qt/Security/bufferOverFlow/a.out 
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied 
SO at 0x7ffff7ffd000
```

I wrote a simple program which prints a string and returns. I was able to execute it directly, by typing "*./a.out*". But when I run it in gdb the error mentioned above happens. I tried compiling the code using the "*-g*" flag and without using it. Both time it gave the same result. Can anyone help me with this issue??

Comment: what other parameters did you pass `gcc`? can you post the full command that you used to compile and link it?

Comment: I tried these commands: 
gcc -g test.c
gcc test.c

Comment: are you using an old kernel? https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=312011

Comment: "Can anyone help me with this issue?" You don't appear to *have* an issue (except for a warning that can be ignored). Does the program *not* print the expected string and exit?

Comment: my problem is that I cannot run the program in gdb

Comment: Yes, you can. You *are* running it. The question is: does it start and hang, or does it not even start? You should be able to differentiate between the two by looking at `ps` output. Once you do, update your question to clarify what it is that's actually happening.

Comment: It would help to see the code being executed.  It does look, from what was posted, that the program is getting executed.  Do you just not see the expected output?  Or, does gdb just "sit" looking hung?  Something else?

Answer (score 3):

That message,

```
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied
```

SO at 0x7ffff7ffd000

is a warning that does not prevent GCC from running `a.out`; at least, it should not.

It is saying that there's a dynamically loaded object used by `a.out` that is missing symbols. Nothing about a.out itself.

You can try to build a.out as a static executable; like this:

```
gcc -static a.c
```

Obviously, add any other compiler arguments needed.

As a static executable, you won't get that warning from GCC.  Those symbols may still be missing, but it should not affect execution of the program.

Comment: This probably does not actually work; the "file" in question is injected into the process address space by the kernel at exec() time, regardless of how the program in question is linked.  Also, the debugger is called GDB.

Comment: @SamB - yup, GDB is trying to run the executable and leads to the warning mentioned.  Give it a try.  "Probably doesn't work" doesn't do much toward resolution.

Comment: @SamB right. Atleast gcc 4.8.1@ubuntu12.04 behaves identically with and without `-static`. My code sample is too simple to show it here

Answer (score 2):

It appears this is a bug in glibc or gdb (depending on where you want to put the blame). It is apparently harmless - gdb will work fine.

It is caused by some magic the Linux kernel performs on binaries it runs. For details, see [Debian bug report 738702](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=738702) and the original [gdb bug report 13097](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13097).

There is a patch to fix this, which Debian applied recently, so the problem no longer occurs with GDB 7.7.1 on Debian.