# gdb: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x2aaaaaaab000

Tags: c++, c, debugging, compiler-construction, gdb

I am trying to debug a C program using gdb.The compile flags that I am using are as below

```
-fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DNO_OLD_ERF_TYPES -Werror  -Wredundant-decls -O2 -DNDEBUG -DBYTESWAP -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g
```

The version of the compiler that I am using is

```
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I debug as

libtool gdb mytool

I set the breakpoint and run the program.The execution doesn't stop at the breakpoint and I get the following warning.

```
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x2aaaaaaab000
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
```

Comment: Check this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548139/gdb-warning-loadable-section-not-found-in-added-symbol-file-system-supplied-dso. This may help you.

Comment: nope.I tried using static.wasn't useful :(

Comment: Debugging non-optimized build is out of the quiestion?

Comment: Are you sure your debugging symbols wasn't stripped away? It's common when building release code. Also, could you try it without libtool?

Comment: @dbrank0 - yes if I turn of optimization the the issue that I am trying to debug is not reproducible.I needs the optimization default optimization level of  -fno-strict-aliasing compiler flag

Comment: You should probably explore the code that you want to put breakpoint at. Perhaps you are putting a breakpoint to something that was inlined or something that was removed altogether. Try disassembling the calling function and putting a breakpoint at appropriate instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting all of the object files and recompiling. I ran into this same problem and was not able to debug my program using gdb. I used cmake to compile and was able to fix the problem by running `make clean; make`

Answer (score -1):

Try dropping the -O2 and the -DNDEBUG.

The -O2 sets the optimization level up a bit so the compiled code may not represent how it is written in the source files and the NDEBUG flag might override the -g